# Can't access my Activision account because the google authentication code was deleted. How do I get it back?

Tags: google

I've been trying to log into my Activision account but I can't because the google authentication code was deleted off the app. I've been trying to contact support but I can't reach them. Is there a way where I can recover the google authentication code back on the google authenticator app.

Comment: Unlikely, though usually services that use 2FA also provide a backup mechanism (e.g. one-time use backup code), just in case of this exact locked-out situation.